# Minimizing open-close scenario

Tags: python, performance, file

I have the following code in `Python` which opens and closes a file in every iteration (using `with` keyword). In 95 % of iterations the file will be the same, so there's no need to open and close it again. Is it possible to optimize it if this optimization has sense?

```
import sys
import re

def createFileName(str, index, number_of_words, suffix):
  pattern = re.compile("[a-zA-Z]+")
  matchList = re.findall(pattern, str)
  matchList = [x.lower() for x in matchList]
  matchList = matchList[0:number_of_words]
  return index + "_".join(matchList) + suffix



if __name__ == "__main__":

  d = [("aaa", True), ("bbb x yyy aa" False), ("ccc aa", False), ("ddd bbb", True), ("eee ddd", False), ("fff x a b" True)] # this list of tuples is just for illustration, it will be usually much bigger.      

  fileName = createFileName(d[0][0], "00", 3, ".txt")
  with open(fileName, "a") as f:
    f.write(d[0][0] + "\n")
  i = 1
  for x in d[1:]:
    if x[1]:
      fileName = createFileName(x[0], "%02d" % i, 3, ".txt")
      i = i + 1
    with open(fileName, "a") as f:
      f.write(x[0] + "\n")
```

Comment: @Graipher `d` is a list of tuples (string, bool). If x[1] is True, new file is created and from this time we write to this file because the following x[1] are usually False, but if it will be True new file will be created. This should explain what is happening. Every iteration has operations open-write-close. `with` makes `close` automatically for us.

Comment: It is a real code. You can take the input, the list of tuples e.g. d = [("aaa", True), ("bbb" False), ("ccc", False), ("ddd", True), ("eee", False), ...] and create a function from my code which takes d as an argument. Should I create another question or edit this question?

Comment: Edit this question, as it has no answers and is currently closed (so no one will be answering while you edit).

Comment: @mdfst13 OK, I edited the question. I only omitted the things that don't relate to the question. The list d is usually generated with human assistance interactively, but we can use data in that format, for the purpose of the question.

Comment: @mdfst13 The list d contains usually True value followed by about 30 False values, so the ratio of True:False is about 1:30, that means, wo don't have to open-close so often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might actually be one of the few cases, where you *don't* want to use `with` with its automatic closing of the file, but do it manually:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    # this list of tuples is just for illustration, it will be usually much bigger.      
    d = [("aaa", True),
         ("bbb x yyy aa" False),
         ("ccc aa", False),
         ("ddd bbb", True),
         ("eee ddd", False),
         ("fff x a b" True)]

    f = None
    i = 0
    try:
        for data, new_file in d:
            if new_file or i == 0:
                if f:
                    f.close()
                fileName = createFileName(data, "%02d" % i, 3, ".txt")
                f = open(fileName, "a")
                i += 1
            f.write(data + "\n")
    finally:
        if f:
            f.close()
```

The `try..finally` is shamelessly stolen from [@MatthiasEttinger's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/144886/98493) to ensure that the file is closed even if the code in-between raises an exception.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is one of those rare case where `with` hits its limits and you should be better served with a `try: ... finally`.

You can `open` the first file, and wraps the rest of the operations into a

```
try:
    # rest of the operations
finally:
    f.close()
```

Then, each time the `fileName` need to change, you `f.close()` and `f = open(...)` again. This way, you only close the file when you won't use it anymore.

As for the rest of the code:

- use 4 spaces per indentation level
- use `snake_case` for variable and functions names
- use unpacking to extract and give a meaningful name to the 2 components of the items in your list
- create `pattern` as a global variable as there is no added value to compile it each time you call `createFileName`
- you can avoid copying `d` when you slice it if you use `iter`

## Proposed improvements

```
import sys
import re


PATTERN = re.compile("[a-zA-Z]+")


def create_file_name(string, index, number_of_words, suffix):
    matches = [x.lower() for x in re.findall(PATTERN, string)]
    return '{:02}{}.{}'.format(index, '_'.join(matches[:number_of_words]), suffix)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    d = [("aaa", True), ("bbb x yyy aa" False), ("ccc aa", False), ("ddd bbb", True), ("eee ddd", False), ("fff x a b" True)] # this list of tuples is just for illustration, it will be usually much bigger.      

    iterator = iter(d)
    file_index = 0
    name, _ = next(iterator)
    filename = create_file_name(name, file_index, 3, 'txt')
    f = open(filename, 'a')
    try:
        f.write(name + '\n')
        for name, new_file in iterator:
            if new_file:
                file_index += 1
                filename = create_file_name(name, file_index, 3, 'txt')
                f.close()
                f = open(filename, 'a')
            f.write(name + '\n')
    finally:
        f.close()
```